# How is deviance defined in H2O Deep Learning if the loss function is not quadratic?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

One can set the parameter “stopping_metric” to “deviance” for the deeplearning algorithm (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html#h2o.estimators.deeplearning.H2ODeepLearningEstimator.stopping_metric).

In the FAQs (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html), the answer to the question “How is deviance computed for a Deep Learning regression model?” is given by the following formula:

“*Loss = Quadratic -> MSE==Deviance For Absolute/Laplace or Huber -> MSE != Deviance.*”

As far as I understand, the deviance equals the MSE if the loss function is quadratic. How is it defined in the other cases (e.g. Huber)? I read the definition that in this case the deviance is not the MSE but what is it then?

Looking forward to your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be here:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/5403e7c7d1e787013105ca977c1a62c249b8ed61/h2o-core/src/main/java/hex/Distribution.java#L69

```
  case huber:
    if (Math.abs(y-f) <= huberDelta) {
      return w * (y - f) * (y - f); // same as wMSE
    } else {
      return 2 * w * (Math.abs(y-f) - huberDelta)*huberDelta; // note quite the same as wMAE
    }
```

I.e. if the error is less than `huberDelta` then it is MSE, otherwise it is a kind of MAE.

E.g. if `y` (correct value) is 0.5, `f` (the prediction) is 0.7, and `huberDelta` is 0.05,(and `w` is 1.0, for simplicity), MSE would be 0.04, but Huber deviance will be `2 * 0.15 * 0.05 = 0.015`. If `f` was 0.6, MSE would be 0.01, while Huber deviance would be `2 * 0.05 * 0.05 = 0.005`.

The huberDelta is set here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/5403e7c7d1e787013105ca977c1a62c249b8ed61/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/deeplearning/DeepLearningModel.java#L387

```
double huberDelta = MathUtils.computeWeightedQuantile(fTrain.vec(get_params()._weights_column), absdiff, get_params()._huber_alpha);
```

Huber Alpha, in turn, can be between 0.0 and 1.0, but defaults to 0.9: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/huber_alpha.html